IntelliJ not showing diff in commit window
I use Windows and IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.4. (Ultimate Edition)
I've been looking at all options and I do not find anything where I can change this behaviour... When I commit I see a window which does not show the Diff inside. I can only Double-Click which will open the diff in a different Tab. See:

Now this is on my Mac using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 (Community Edition). How can I get the same picture on my Windows IntelliJ of the picture above?


As per this response in the JetBrains support platform, this is enabled by default on new installations, and the way to disable it is by unchecking Settings > Version Control > Commit > Use non-modal commit interface.

